# Tekton git-clone task is not found even though I see it in tkn task ls

Tags: tekton-pipelines

I have installed tkn cli and installed 0.8 version of git-clone using this command:

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tektoncd/catalog/main/task/git-clone/0.8/git-clone.yaml

However, when i run the pipeline, i get the following error:

PIpeline can't be Run; it contains Tasks that don't exist: Couldn't retrieve Task "git-clone": failed to get task: tasks.tekton.dev "git-clone" not found

1. Tried installing the git-clone task using `tkn hub install task git-clone`. It had issues with version.
2. Installed by applying kubectl like I said above. Now tkn shows the task but the pipeline fails.

Comment: Make sure you installed that task in the same namespace your Pipeline is located into. Re-create a PipelineRun (if that Task was missing when you created your previous PipelineRun: creating it later on won't un-block your run)

Answer (score 0):

Im what peeps will call k8s tekton noob, but I also faced this. Ensure they are in the pipeline and tasks are in the same namespace. You can check this with

```
kubectl get the task -A
```

Typically the git-clone will be placed in the default namespace, and per default, when you run a pipeline, if no namespace is set, look for the task in default also. But if Task is in, e.g. namespace B then just and to your apply cmd "-n B" to put it in the same namespace.